# SecurityException when trying to query list of videos

Tags: android, android-sdcard, android-securityexception, android-storage

My code is trying to get a list of videos on user's device using the query but I am getting security exception on devices like Samsung Galaxy S7, S8 which are very popular devices and can't be ignored.

I do have READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE and WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permissions in my manifest file.
My code is using the new permission mode by adding following code at app launch:

```
private void requestPermission() {

        if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(this, android.Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Write External Storage permission allows us to do store images. Please allow this permission in App Settings.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        } else {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{android.Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, 15);
        }
    }
```

My code is:

```
Uri uri;
Cursor cursor;
uri = MediaStore.Video.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;

String[] projection = {MediaStore.Video.Media._ID,MediaStore.Video.Media.DURATION, MediaStore.Video.Media.DISPLAY_NAME, MediaStore.Video.Media.DATA};

final String orderBy = MediaStore.Images.Media.DATE_TAKEN;
cursor = getApplicationContext().getContentResolver().query(uri, projection, null, null, orderBy + " DESC");

while (cursor.moveToNext()) {

    int column_index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);//Instead of "MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA" can be used "_data"
    Uri filePathUri = Uri.parse(cursor.getString(column_index));
    Uri var5 = Uri.withAppendedPath(Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, ContentUtill.getLong(cursor));
    String fileName = filePathUri.getLastPathSegment().toString();

    VideoData var7 = new VideoData(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Video.Media.DISPLAY_NAME)),
            var5,
            cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow( MediaStore.Video.Media.DATA)),
            cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow( MediaStore.Video.Media.DURATION)));
    this.videoList.add(var7);
}
```

I see security exception at following line in above code:

```
cursor = getApplicationContext().getContentResolver().query(uri, projection, null, null, orderBy + " DESC");
```

The stack trace of the exception is:

```
Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: 
  at android.os.Parcel.readException (Parcel.java:1599)
  at android.database.DatabaseUtils.readExceptionFromParcel (DatabaseUtils.java:188)
  at android.database.DatabaseUtils.readExceptionFromParcel (DatabaseUtils.java:140)
  at android.content.ContentProviderProxy.query (ContentProviderNative.java:421)
  at android.content.ContentResolver.query (ContentResolver.java:498)
  at android.content.ContentResolver.query (ContentResolver.java:441)
  at video.format.converter.view.SelectVideoActivity.getVideoList (SelectVideoActivity.java:92)
  at video.format.converter.view.SelectVideoActivity.access$000 (SelectVideoActivity.java:37)
  at video.format.converter.view.SelectVideoActivity$loadVideo.doInBackground (SelectVideoActivity.java:210)
  at video.format.converter.view.SelectVideoActivity$loadVideo.doInBackground (SelectVideoActivity.java:194)
  at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call (AsyncTask.java:295)
  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run (FutureTask.java:237)
```

What is wrong in my code and what is the recommended way of getting videos list which works on all type of new and old devices. (API 14+)

Comment: checkSelfPermission will only check if permission is granted or not . Are you using Activity.requestPermissions() to grant runtime permission in your code ? before accessing the video list

Comment: @Gautam yes I am calling requestpermission on app launch. I have updated my code in the question

Comment: Then the only possible way is either the permission is not being granted by the user or may be even by granting the permission user can disable the permission by going through settings. I would suggest just check before accessing the method if permission is granted or not as a safe check.

Comment: Any solution ? I am also facing same issue still. Unfortunately I could not reproduce but in users devices on play store I am facing this issue,